# Getting ServletContext for FreemarkerConfigurationFactory

Tags: java, freemarker, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to create a custom FreemarkerConfigurationFactory, which help me to enable setting some settings, so that I can access methods in ftl templates. The problem is that I can't find out a way to obtain the `ServletContext`.

- @Context injection doesn't work, as I'm not within a Resource class
- I tried adding the `ServletContextListener` interface, which worked at first, but I soon figured out that for every request the FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory is newly created. So after the first call it disappears. It's possible to keep this variable static somewhere, but it just smells as bad practices and I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong.

Any idea how I would be able to correctly obtain an instance to the `ServletContext`?

```
public class FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory implements FreemarkerConfigurationFactory, ServletContextListener {
    Configuration configuration;

    public FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory() {
        this.configuration = new Configuration(new freemarker.template.Version(2, 3, 22));
        BeansWrapperBuilder builder = new BeansWrapperBuilder(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_21);
        builder.setExposeFields(true);
        ObjectWrapper wrapper = builder.build();
        configuration.setObjectWrapper(wrapper);
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration() {
        return this.configuration;
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }
}
```

---

### Update: 1

I've created the following, which to me doesn't look that bad.

```
@WebListener
public final class FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory implements FreemarkerConfigurationFactory, ServletContextListener {

      @Override
      public Configuration getConfiguration() {
            return Instance.getConfiguration();
      }

      @Override
      public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
            Instance.setServletContext(sce.getServletContext());
      }

      @Override
      public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
      }

      private static class Instance {

            private static Configuration configuration;

            static {
                  configuration = new Configuration(new freemarker.template.Version(2, 3, 22));
                  BeansWrapperBuilder builder = new BeansWrapperBuilder(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_22);
                  builder.setExposeFields(true);
                  ObjectWrapper wrapper = builder.build();
                  configuration.setObjectWrapper(wrapper);
            }

            public static void setServletContext(ServletContext context) {
                  configuration.setServletContextForTemplateLoading(context, "/");
            }

            public static Configuration getConfiguration() {
                  return configuration;
            }
      }
}
```

I'd rather not use a static class though. If someone can tell me how to get access to the ServletContext in a better way, I'd love to hear it!

---

### Update: 2

I've removed the BeansWrapperBuild and replaced it with a DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder. Everything works perfectly so far!

```
@WebListener
public final class FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory implements FreemarkerConfigurationFactory, ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration() {
        return Instance.getConfiguration();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        Instance.setServletContext(sce.getServletContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // Ignore
    }

    private static class Instance {

        private static Configuration configuration;

        static {
            configuration = new Configuration(new freemarker.template.Version(2, 3, 22));
            DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder builder = new DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder(new freemarker.template.Version(2, 3, 22));
            builder.setExposeFields(true);
            DefaultObjectWrapper wrapper = builder.build();
            configuration.setObjectWrapper(wrapper);
        }

        public static void setServletContext(ServletContext context) {
            configuration.setServletContextForTemplateLoading(context, "/");
        }

        public static Configuration getConfiguration() {
            return configuration;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but the choice of the `ObjectWrapper` looks like call for trouble. `DefaultObjectWrapper` with `incompatibleImprovements` 2.3.22 is usually the best, but if you really need `BeansWrapper`, `simpleMapWrapper` should be `true` at least.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know it would be better to use the DefaultObjectWrapper. I've updated the post and posted my final code.

Comment: As it's unrelated to your problem, an in-place update would have been fine. BTW, you can use `Configuration.VERSION_2_3_22` instead of `new Version(2, 3, 22)`.